# Saving Video to PhotosAlbum Is Slow

Tags: ios, avfoundation

Apple's camera app seems to save video straight to the photos album. I'm wondering if that capability can be accomplished by us mere mortal developers.

Both methods I've come across and tested, copy a video file to the photos album. The larger the file, the longer it takes to save. A 2 minute creation can vary in the save time. Two timings I have are, 45 seconds, and 1 minute 12 seconds to copy to copy files about 150MB in size. A file of similar size from the Apple Camera app can take as little as 6 seconds.

I've looked at the AVCam demo code and it uses one of the two methods I've already tested.

> ALAssetsLibrary instance method writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:completionBlock:

> UIKit Function UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum

I'm using AVFoundation to connect to the camera and open up a stream to a file. For context, the following is where I open that file. The movieURLPath is a file reference in my apps document directory area.

```
outputWriter = [AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL: [projectPaths movieURLPath]  fileType: AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error: &error];
```

When the file has been closed by stopping the recording, I eventually get to this line.

```
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum ([projectPaths movieFilePath], self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), nil);
```

Does anyone have any other options to speed up the writing process? Clearly my preference would be to have movieURLPath pointing to a file in the PhotosAlbum. It would be optimal to open the file in that folder instead, which is what I think Apple has done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving this to a background thread or use GCD so your UI doesn't get blocked. Checkout how to use GCD here.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/BlocksGCD/_index.html

Comment: I've been thinking the same thing. I already have a setup for saving an interrupted capture, so this would be helpful. Of course if the user goes to the PhotosAlbum, the file may not yet be there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the Camera application works, but I know how I fixes the same issue on my application.

Using the same AVCam code example from WWDC 2010, under the AVCamCaptureManager you can find the following message:

```
- (NSURL *) tempFileURL
{
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"output.mov"]];
}
```

What I did was changing it to something like the following:

```
- (NSURL *) tempFileURL
{
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Documents"], @"output.mov"]];
}
```

which will dump all camera output to the application document folder. Now all I needed to do is when the recording ended to rename the temp file to something unique on the document folder, which is a very quick process with no dependence on the file size.

I've gave the user the option to save the file to the library but it's still a very long process. I couldn't find a better solution using ALAssetsLibrary. Would love to hear about something that actually works!

ps. If you're developing to IO5 I'm sure apple changed/replaced that Framework completely due to iCloud.

ps2. I truly believe that Apple did the same on the camera application, but this API is not available.

Comment: Coming up with a unique name for the saved file is easy enough, but it doesn't really solve the problem. As I mentioned in the comment above, I'm concerned that the user will think the file is MIA if they go straight to the PhotosAlbum. I haven't supplied a playback interface for the local saved file.  WTF! I can't type a return for a new paragraph in this damn editor.

Comment: To simplify the problem, you are trying to avoid the copy process of the video file. Unfortunately in current ALAssetsLibrary API it is impossible (from what i've known and tested). Again, this does not apply to iOS 5.

Comment: Yes, I prefer something like opening the file path directly in the PhotosAlbum or something like the Unix mv command. I'm don't know why you added that 'does not apply to iOS 5' comment. It does.

Answer (score 0):

Run that code in the background (like logan suggested):

```
#define ASYNC(block) dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), block)

ASYNC(^{
    // save to photo album
});
```